# Is it possible to construct embedded generics in Swift?

Tags: swift, generics

Let's say I have a protocol and a struct like so:

```
protocol A {
    var someType: UnrelatedProtocol.Type { get }
}

struct B<T: UnrelatedProtocol> {
    var anotherThing: T?
}
```

And I want to use these together like this:

```
struct C<T: A> {
    typealias SomeThing = (B<T.someType>) -> Void
}
```

Is this possible in Swift? I have been playing around with this but cannot get it quite right. Maybe it's not possible but I feel like I should be able to do something like this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all we have

```
protocol UnrelatedProtocol { }
```

Now we need to define an associated type inside the protocol `A`

```
protocol A {
    associatedtype SomeType: UnrelatedProtocol
    var someType: SomeType { get }
}
```

And finally

```
struct B<T: UnrelatedProtocol> {
    var anotherThing: T?
}

struct C<T: A> {
    typealias Logic = (B<T.SomeType>) -> ()
}
```